# What is the proper way to use the belt adjusting bolt when changing belts on a civic?

Tags: belt-tensioner

I found this great answer, the second one: http://www.justanswer.com/honda/1k3fw-change-alternator-belt-2003-honda-civic.html

On part (7) and (8) it says to turn the belt adjusting bolt counter-clockwise to loosen the belt. But how do I gauge the bolt and belt tension after I put the new belts on? How do I know when I've screwed the bolt enough, too much or too little?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the diagram which they posted:

[image]

You are looking for the deflection point at "**A**". Normal deflection is considered about 1/2" (or just under 2cm). As the guy in the instruction says, tighten up the belt, then run the engine for about 5 minutes, then readjust the belts again.

If the belt is too tight, you are putting extra wear on the belt and accessories. If the belt is too loose, you run the risk of the belt jumping off, extra belt wear, and/or an accessory slipping, which means you'd not be getting the best performance out of any part of that which the belt drives.

Comment: Thank you!
When you say belt deflection that is to say when I put my finger or hand and press down against the belt it should belt downwards no more than 1/2"? Also is it ok to run the car with the wheel off the vehicle? and should I twist the belts at all isn't there a test with that as well?

Comment: Just use your thumb and push down. If you have about a thumbs width difference (top of thumb is where the belt was normally) you're golden. If you are talking about the wheel/tire, then yes you can, but you need to ensure your tires are chocked and the e-brake is engaged. Just be safe about it. In this case, there's no need to twist the belt to test anything.